# When should I seek medical help for food poisoning?

Tags: food-poisoning

Last four days have been terrible! I ate at a restaurant and few hours later, I felt nauseous, lost my appetite. By night time I had a fever, chills, and fatigued. Next day I was unable to eat as I had no appetite and than I started having green bile diarrhea with no actual 'feces' just water and bile.

I no longer have a fever and chills but the appetite and diarrhea still remain. Will this pass on it's own or should I seek medical attention?

Comment: We can't and we shouldn't guess over the internet. These questions can be answered by your doctor.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a theoretical answer, I can't give a medical advice here.

The symptoms, as described by the OP, are possibly from viral or bacterial food poisoning. In mild cases, the symptoms can go away [on its own](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/food-poisoning/basics/treatment/con-20031705) within a week. If not, a visit to a doctor is recommended.

Diarrhea can quickly lead to dehydration (symptoms: fatigue, dry mouth, less frequent urination, dark yellow urine, loss of body weight). To correct dehydration, one needs to drink water (or "oral rehydration solution" you can buy in any bigger store or in a drugstore) until the urine becomes clear and the body weight is back to normal. You can eat what you are able to.